# Materials not showing in Viewport or Render?

Tags: materials

so i have this little problem. My materials are not showing up, neither in Material View nor in Render View. These are basic materials made in Blender (no image textures). The file I'm working on was created in 2.8, now I updated to 2.91 and it is not working anymore.

Here are some pictures to make it more clear.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pev39.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xpoR.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQzyb.jpg

Comment: Apparently the links were not saved, so here they are.

Comment: Use the [edit] link  to modify your question

Comment: You are in solid mode

Comment: Did u even look at the screenshots, there are three u know. Anyways, i tried it with other files and it seems to be a general problem. In none of my files it shows the materials. Is there any kind of setting that might cause this.

Comment: Ok i just found out that it is probably not the cause of the update. I was already on the new version when everything was still fine. So im very clueless now.

Comment: If you have an AMD GPU, roll back your drivers to an older version.

Comment: Yaeh I just updated my drivers a few days ago. Rolling the GPU driver back worked, so thank you very much.